# How do I correctly get the event target in IE when document.click event is registered in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, dom-events

I have registered the click event on document object, I want to be able to branch logic depending on the target that was clicked, the targets are divs on the page

IE 7-9 has a strange bug that absolutely positioned divs when clicked, do not register as the target of the event, this happens only in IE, the target that is returned is the underlying divs below the absolutely positioned one.

Is there a fix/hack to handle it, surely IE is always making trouble?

Comment: I am not sure about your exactly situation but this might help you! http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: I think I have reproduced what you are doing(hopefully). But it is working for me. Ref: http://jsfiddle.net/vg2cm/

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you are getting the event target correctly for IE.

```
var target = event ? event.target : window.event.srcElement;
```

Comment: Probably old, but shouldn't hurt: `if (t.nodeType == 3) t = t.parentNode;` Safari fix from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Comment: I did "target = event.target ? event.target : window.event.srcElement;"  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did this code a long time ago, I'm almost sure it works on IE7, it works perfectly in IE8, Firefox and Chrome:

```
function getTarget(e) {
    var evn = e || window.event;
    return evn.srcElement || e.target;
}
```